# HTML form data to JSON format

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I am trying to post some data from an HTML form to an webserver. Requirement is, The POST data should be a JSON data. The expected JSON from server is

```
{
    "version": "1.0.1",
    "sensors": [
        {
            "sensor": "sensorID",
            "output": [
                {
                    "name": "sensorName",
                     "type": "sensorType"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

were `sensorID`, `sensorName`, `sensorType` corresponds to the input fields from HTML form. Others should be as it is. My code is:

```
<html>
   <head>
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
   </head>
  <body>
    <h2>Create Sensor</h2>
    <form id="form">
    <form enctype='application/json'>
      <input name='version' value='1.0.1'>
      <input name='sensors[0][sensor]' value=''>
      <input name='sensors[0][output][0][name]' value=''>
      <input name='sensors[0][output][0][type]' value=''>
      <br>
      <input id="input" type="submit" name="submit" value="Create Sensor" />
    </form>
    <script>
$.ajaxSetup({
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json"
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#input').click(function () {
        var send = JSON.stringify($("#form").serializeArray());
        alert(send);
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://posttestserver.com/post.php",

            type: "POST",
            data: send,
            success: function (send, status, jqXHR) {
                alert(JSON.stringify(send));
            },

            error: function (jqXHR, status) {
                alert(JSON.stringify(jqXHR));
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
    </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

I am having this output:

```
[{
    "name": "version",
    "value": "1.0.1"
}, {
    "name": "sensors[0][sensor]",
    "value": ""
}, {
    "name": "sensors[0][output][0][name]",
    "value": ""
}, {
    "name": "sensors[0][output][0][type]",
    "value": ""
}]
```

Can anyone please Help me out? I am trying hard. But as I am new to this, probably missing something that's why not able to solve this problem. It will be very helpful for me if anyone please guide me regarding this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what's you code in php file rendering this out?

Comment: Also try to **print_r($_POST)** and add the result to your question, it may help to figure out the problem.

Comment: nothing. I am having this alert: {"readyState":0,"responseText":"","status":0,"statusText":"error"}

Comment: You should get code of this file (http://posttestserver.com/post.php).

Comment: I am not getting. Where to add print_r($_POST) ? Can you please help me? I don't know much about these things. Just a novice.

Comment: post server returns what is dumped. It is showing nothing

Comment: you have many problems in your code , if you didn't solved it yet let me know to provide u with the correct choices

Comment: @NinjaDevelopers Yes please if you like to help

Comment: @anupam_on There'll be just one set of sensor or many..?

Comment: @ T J just one sensor

Comment: @anupam_on then can't you create a custom json in the desired format as mentioned in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25280427/2333214)…?

Comment: is it 1 sensor or more than one ?

Comment: @NinjaDevelopers one sensor

Comment: @T J I tried and posted the code too. It is not happening. I have to take input from form and then post. I have given the output too. The formed JSON which is not matching with my requirement

Comment: okay I've updated my answer with 100% working solution plz give it a try

Comment: and let me know if its worked with u plz

Answer (score 0):

Form your own JSON rather than using `$("#form");`,
Like

```
     var sensorArr=new Array();
    //push your values to SensorArr
     var data= {
        "version": $("input[name='version']").val(),
        "sensors": [
            {
                "sensor": "sensorID",
                "output": sensorArr;
            }
        ]
    }
```

and send this `data`  to AJAX

Answer (score 0):

how about change html?

```
<input name='sensors[0][sensor]' value=''>
```

to

```
<input class="d_sensors" name='sensor' value=''>
```

read javascript

```
var data = {};
data['version'] = $("input[name='version']").val();
data['sensors'] = [];
var sensorsList = $(".d_sensors");
for (var i = 0; i < sensorsList.length; i++) {
  var $item = sensorsList.eq(i);
  var sensor = {};
  sensor['sensor'] = $item.val();
  sensor['output'] = [];
// do same way
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Will in your case you need to setup JSON Object , **why !!**

because when Html inputs submitted as Array each key mean new array you cannot group them in one object as you requested , to do this you need to use custom javascript array

**this is full working example to your case**

**1- first** : remove array name from your inputs to be like this :

```
  <input name='sensors_sensor' value=''>
  <input name='sensors_name' value=''>
  <input name='sensors_type' value=''>
```

**2- second** : add this object inside form post request ( AJAX )

```
  var fromData = { 
  "version"  : $('input[name=version]').val(),
  "sensors"  : [ { "sensor" : $('input[name=sensors_name]').val(),
                   "output" : [{  "name" : $('input[name=sensors_name]').val() , 
                                  "type": $('input[name=sensors_type]').val()}] } ],

  };
```

**3- third :** if you like to add more inputs just add it inside the `formData` object

**4- finally :** add `formData` object to your Ajax form and enjoy

```
$.ajax({
            url: "http://posttestserver.com/post.php",

            type: "POST",
            data: formData,
            success: function (send, status, jqXHR) {
                alert(JSON.stringify(send));
            },
```

Comment: Hi, the json output is valid but after posting in server it is showing this error: 

{"readyState":4,"responseText":"","status":400,"statusText":"Bad Request"}

Comment: check this link , this is another issue , http://pcsupport.about.com/od/findbyerrormessage/a/400error.htm